# Windows filter traffic on hosted network

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I have set up a hosted wi-fi network bridged to an Ethernet connection by following [this guide](http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/254729-turn-windows-7-laptop-into-wireless-repeater-one-wireless-adapter.html). The network works, but I want to be able to monitor/block certain traffic going through the hosted network to the Ethernet connection. How can I do this?

Comment: @techie007 pyshaper is for linux. NetLimiter is paid, and the link for Network Magic is broken. Furthermore, I can't find any legit looking download sites for network magic on google. All in all, that question was pretty useless.

Comment: It's still the same question (IMO), perhaps place a comment and [a bounty](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) on the existing question to garner newer/different answers.

Comment: I know it's the same question, when I posted this I didn't know that it was called "shaping" so I had not found that question, but I'm just saying it's pretty useless.